# Sending UDM message from Raspberry via SIM900a GPRS module in python. 1nce provider

Tags: python

I'm trying to send a UDP message via GPRS service from Raspberry but nothing happens. Here is my code. Any advice?
Sorry, but this is my first question on StackOverflow.
Thanks

```
import time
import serial

def receive(ser):
    print("READ:")
    time.sleep(1)
    data_left = ser.inWaiting()
    while data_left > 0:
        received_data = ser.read()              #read serial port
        time.sleep(0.3)
        data_left = ser.inWaiting()             #check for remaining byte
        received_data += ser.read(data_left)
        print(received_data)


ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyS0", 9600)
time.sleep(1)
ser.write("AT+CGATT = 1".encode())
receive(ser)
ser.write("AT+CSTT=\"iot.1nce.net\"".encode())
receive(ser)
ser.write("AT+CIICR".encode())
receive(ser)
ser.write("AT+CIFSR".encode())
receive(ser)
ser.write("AT+CIPSTART=\"UDP\",\"100.22.34.22\",8000".encode())
receive(ser)
ser.write("AT+CIPSEND".encode())
receive(ser)
ser.write(("{\"testo\":\"12345\"}" + chr(26)).encode())
receive(ser)
```

Comment: You might want to clarify what you mean by "UDM" and "UDP" message -- I suspect one or both of these is a typo and may confuse the issue a bit.

Comment: yes is a typo. I meant UDP

Comment: Ah, okay.  I missed the CIPSTART line, did not realize you could send UDP packets that way.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out your power supply. SIM900A needs 5V,2A. If the voltage or current is not sufficient, it will not function.

Comment: The sim900a is powered by a separate PSU at 4V and can provide 60 watt. The sim900a device should work from 3.6 to 4.5V